# Where can I find climate analogs?

Tags: meteorology, climatology

It is an unusual year where I'm at, I'd like to go and see similar climatological years for the north america, more particularly for average pressure, maybe 500mb or 700mb. How would I do this

Edit: Regional or State would be fine. Average pressure on a 1 month or seasonal basis.

Context: I am simply trying to compare the year, if there is a better way to do this than pressure, even temperature and precip would be nice. I'm looking to find simmilarities between years on a regional level. A map of average pressure on a seasonal basis would be awesome.

Region: North America regional, but the finer resolution the better

License: I'd like this to be free.

Format: Any format is acceptable.

Non-answers: I'm looking for more then the NOAA Climatic Data Center can provide.

Authority: Any source is acceptable

Comment: Are you talking total pressure, or the mean pattern.  Either way, wonder if it might be a little complex if looking to match weather to similar years, since a year of alternating strong high and low pressures wouldn't show up all that different to a year of fairly quiet patterns.

Comment: In what form do you want the data, and what geographical distribution? (one number for entire North America seems a bit pointless). Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and update your question.